# BLE WRITE and Read Issue?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

Please anyone help me, I already tried many ways. 
BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt
`mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mWriteCharacteristic)` 
return true 
but `readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic)` return false.I could not find correct manuals for this,but tried many ways there was no clear sample for BEL android.`
    package com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt;

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattService;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothProfile;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import static com.example.android.bluetoothlegatt.DeviceControlActivity.hexArray;

public class BluetoothLeService extends Service {
    private final static String TAG = BluetoothLeService.class.getSimpleName();

    private BluetoothManager mBluetoothManager;
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private String mBluetoothDeviceAddress;
    private BluetoothGatt mBluetoothGatt;
    private int mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;

    private static final int STATE_DISCONNECTED = 0;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTING = 1;
    private static final int STATE_CONNECTED = 2;

    public final static String ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED";
    public final static String ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED";
    public final static String ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE";
    public final static String EXTRA_DATA =
            "com.example.bluetooth.le.EXTRA_DATA";

    public final static UUID UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT =
            UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT);
    private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            String intentAction;
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTED;
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
                Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" +
                        mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());

            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                mConnectionState = STATE_DISCONNECTED;
                Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
                broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                         int status) {
            Log.i(TAG,"onCharacteristicRead::"+status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {


                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            Log.i(TAG,"onCharacteristicChanged::"+characteristic);
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicWrite(final  BluetoothGatt gatt, final  BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
            byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
            Log.i(TAG,"onCharacteristicWrite Response::"+bytesToHex(data));
        }

    };

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,
                                 final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
            int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
            int format = -1;
            if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
                format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
                Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT16.");
            } else {
                format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
                Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT8.");
            }
            final int heartRate = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("Received heart rate: %d", heartRate));
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, String.valueOf(heartRate));
        } else {
            final byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
            if (data != null && data.length > 0) {
                final StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(data.length);
                for(byte byteChar : data)
                    stringBuilder.append(String.format("%02X ", byteChar));
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, new String(data) + "\n" + stringBuilder.toString());
            }
        }
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        BluetoothLeService getService() {
            return BluetoothLeService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        close();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();


    public boolean initialize() {
        if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
            mBluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
            if (mBluetoothManager == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to initialize BluetoothManager.");
                return false;
            }
        }

        mBluetoothAdapter = mBluetoothManager.getAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to obtain a BluetoothAdapter.");
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }


    public boolean connect(final String address) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || address == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized or unspecified address.");
            return false;
        }
        if (mBluetoothDeviceAddress != null && address.equals(mBluetoothDeviceAddress)
                && mBluetoothGatt != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Trying to use an existing mBluetoothGatt for connection.");
            if (mBluetoothGatt.connect()) {
                mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        final BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        if (device == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Device not found.  Unable to connect.");
            return false;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, mGattCallback);
        Log.d(TAG, "Trying to create a new connection.");
        mBluetoothDeviceAddress = address;
        mConnectionState = STATE_CONNECTING;
        return true;
    }
    public void disconnect() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
    }
    public void close() {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.close();
        mBluetoothGatt = null;
    }
    public void readCharacteristic(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
    }
    public void setCharacteristicNotification(BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                                              boolean enabled) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, enabled);
        if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = characteristic.getDescriptor(
                    UUID.fromString(SampleGattAttributes.CLIENT_CHARACTERISTIC_CONFIG));
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        }
    }
    public List<BluetoothGattService> getSupportedGattServices() {
        if (mBluetoothGatt == null) return null;

        return mBluetoothGatt.getServices();
    }

    public void readCustomCharacteristic() {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000bc01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
        if(mCustomService == null){
            Log.w(TAG, "Custom BLE Service not found");
            return;
        }
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic mReadCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("0000bd01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
        UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00002901-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");
        Log.i(TAG,"BluetoothGattCharacteristic Des::"+mReadCharacteristic.getDescriptor(uuid));
        BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = mReadCharacteristic.getDescriptor(uuid);
        Log.i(TAG,"BluetoothGattDescriptor is::"+descriptor.getUuid());
        descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
        mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(mReadCharacteristic, true);
        mReadCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("0000bd01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));

        byte[] data = mReadCharacteristic.getValue();
        Log.i(TAG,"onCharacteristicWrite Response::"+bytesToHex(data));
        if(mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(mReadCharacteristic) == false) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read characteristic");
        }
        else{
            Log.w(TAG, "Suucess to read characteristic");
            mBluetoothGatt.notify();
        }
    }
    public void writeCustomCharacteristic(byte value[]) {
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || mBluetoothGatt == null) {
            Log.w(TAG, "BluetoothAdapter not initialized");
            return;
        }
        BluetoothGattService mCustomService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(UUID.fromString("0000bc01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
        if(mCustomService == null){
            Log.w(TAG, "Custom BLE Service not found");
            return;
        }
        BluetoothGattCharacteristic mWriteCharacteristic = mCustomService.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString("0000bd01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"));
        try {
            byte [] message = new byte [6];
            message[0] = (byte) 0x1B;
            message[1] = (byte) 0x00;
            message[2] = (byte) 0x02;
            message[3] = (byte) 0x25;
            message[4] = (byte) 0x27;
            message[5] = (byte) 0x1b;
            mWriteCharacteristic.setValue(message);
            if(mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(mWriteCharacteristic)==true){
                Log.w(TAG, "Write Char Success");
            }
            else{
                Log.w(TAG, "Write Char Faile");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: read the source code, in your case  1.BluetoothGattService is null may return false,pls check it; 2.BluetoothDevice is null may return false;3.remote device is busy may return false; 4.check RemoteException happened

Comment: show sufficient code to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @GPS i follow this woking sample http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/how-to-communicate-with-a-custom-ble-using-an-android-app/

Answer (score 0):

After you call `mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);` you need to wait for the corresponding callback until you can execute the read command.

Comment: After executing  the writeDescriptor i am not getting any callback.